# Python multiprocessing - 'TypeError('self.profile cannot be converted to a Python object for pickling',)'

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have defined a function in Python that uses the [Gambit](https://gambitproject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to find the Nash equilibria of a game theory model. I have twenty different games and have been able to write a for-loop that finds the Nash equilibria of each of them. The output for a given game looks like this:

> ('Polynomial Systems Method: ', [<NashProfile for 'family': [[0.0,
> 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]>])

Now I am trying to parallelize this task, using `apply_async` in the `multiprocessing` package, using code like this:

```
# Open the pool for parallelization
pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())

# Run a loop in parallel to find the Nash equilibria of all the families
nasheqobj = {f:pool.apply_async(find_nash, args=[f]) for f in range(20)}
pool.close()
pool.join()

# Retrieve the output of the loop
nasheq_fams = {}
for f in range(20):
    nasheq_fams[f] = nasheqobj[f].get()
print('Results from running in parallel: ', nasheq_fams)
```

However, when I try to retrieve the output of the loop, stored in `nasheqobj`, to create the dictionary `nasheq_fams`, I get this error coming from `nasheq_fams[f] = nasheqobj[f].get()`:

> raise self._value multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error
> sending result: '[<NashProfile for 'family': [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
> [0.0, 1.0]]>]'. Reason: 'TypeError('self.profile cannot be converted
> to a Python object for pickling',)'

The problem seems to be related with the way the output of my function is formatted (e.g., `[<NashProfile for 'family': [[0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0]]>]`), but I don't know what is wrong with it...

Comment: I'm not a python pickling expert, but I know some objects cannot be pickled.  I would simplify my object down to basically nothing, to get down a pickle-able object.  Then add its components back until I find the component that broke the pickling.  The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/pickle.html) has a section on what can and cannot be pickled.

Comment: I don't know if gambit releases the python GIL, but if if does, it would be a good candidate for multithreading. A thread pool doesn't need to pickle the result, bypassing this error. Try `pool = mp.Pool.ThreadPool()` to see if its faster than non-threaded.

Comment: If the game can be serialized, do that in your multiprocess worker and return the serialized result. You could even write it to a file and read in the parent.

Comment: @tdelaney Reading the code, gambit seems to invoke an external solver using the subprocess module. A thread pool is a promising approach.

Comment: @NickODell - Interesting. Gambit itself may already be multithreaded, and further parallelization may just cause more thrashing. Experimentation needed.

Comment: @tdelaney Oh, I don't mean that Gambit is multithreaded - it seems to launch a subprocess and wait for that subprocess to finish. [source](https://github.com/gambitproject/gambit/blob/master/src/python/gambit/nash.py#L62). Just that waiting for a subprocess releases GIL.

Comment: @NickODell - right, but does that subprocess use threads or its own sub-subprocesses to do the work? I think you'ld have to launch one and check process / thread count in the OS. Or just try a thread pool of 1 and another at something approaching cpu_count and see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your comments. I did a bit more research, and it turns out that the *NashProfile* class isn't a pure Python class and doesn't support being pickled. At the end I saved the information out of the *NashProfile* into a list and passed that around, and it worked.